# Why can't javascript use .style.color in if statments

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, colors, styles

When in javascript you can't use if statments using the color of an element as a contition, for example there following if statment returns false always

```
    document.getElementById('t').style.color = "rgb(0,0,255)"

    alert(document.getElementById('t').style.color)

    if(document.getElementById('t').style.color == rgb(0,0,255))
    {
    alert("if")
    }
```

and the alert in line 3 returns rgb(0,0,255) meaning that the browser does in fact use rgb for the color. but alert("if") never works

could someone help me with a way to get this to work or find an alternative way to mark a button (i need to do this for a button, not radio button) that isnt changing its class, for example changing some insignificant thing that the javascript will be able to check that isnt the color

Thank you in advance!
:)

edit - Thanks for the answers, that helped, i feel like an idiot kinda :S i just selected the one with the least points to their name

Comment: You don't have an `rgb` function.  You need a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"rgb(0,0,255)" != rgb(0,0,255)
```

Add quotes to the if statement. Right now you're checking if the string "rgb(0,0,255)" is equal to the result of the function rgb with three ints (0,0,255) passed as arguments.

The value in color is treated like a string. These two are different as well:

```
"rgb(0,0,255)" != "rgb(0, 0, 255)"
```

...because of the spaces in the values. You might want to convert them to hex first and do the comparison there, as there's less chance that you'll run into a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in alert window two more spaces:

```
"rgb(0, 0, 255)"
```

And dont forget the commas.

You can use: "blue" or "#0000ff" as well.

Comment: This is incorrect; at least in Chrome. The browser will return the string to which the color was set (plus some normalization, like spaces between RGB values). It will not check for equivalent colors. "rgb(0,0,255" != "blue")

Comment: yeah, i found you cant use blue or the hex colour

Comment: Because you have to use it consistently: "blue" == "blue"

Answer (score 0):

You are facing two issues here:

1. As has been mentioned twice, above, you need to be checking for a string value, not a the return of a non-existant function call (which is what `rgb(0,0,255)` is, in this situation . . . the function `rgb` is not defined in your code).
2. The "set" functionality of `style.color` will accept a much wider format of inputs than the "get" functionality will output.  If you input "red", `style.color` will also output "red".  However, if you input "rgb(0,0,255)", `style.color` will actually output "rgb(0, 0, 255)" (notice the spaces after the commas).

You *can* check the value this way, but, if you do, you need to be aware of exactly what to check for, in order for it to work.